# Using Python datetime instead of Zope DateTime

Tags: python, datetime, zope

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/DateTime mentions that it is better to use python datetime rather than Zope DateTime. I believe this is done by invoking External Methods. Is there any other way of doing this as I don't think one would like to create an external method for all the kind of stuff that needs to be imported ?

Comment: You should ask separate questions separately. Also, the first question is unclear and the second vague. What are you tyring to do?

Comment: Have removed the second question. In Zope, whenever a new Python Script is created using ZMI, it is in Restricted mode and as such cannot import Python modules like datetime etc. So the only way to do it is to write the logic on the filesystem and access this file using an External Method from Zope. My question was to find an alternative approach to this.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Zope, but why not just use Zope DateTime? To reverse the order of that the package description says, "You're probably better off using Python's built-in datetime module ... unless you need to communicate with Zope 2 APIs".

Comment: I do use Zope DateTime. Was curious to find out how do they do it using Python without External methods

Answer (score 0):

The class `DateTime` from module `DateTime` can be imported in the Zope restricted mode simply because it's declared as public in the package [`AccessControl`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/AccessControl/3.0.11).  In its top level [`__init__.py`](https://github.com/zopefoundation/AccessControl/blob/3.0.11/src/AccessControl/__init__.py#L40)

```
ModuleSecurityInfo('DateTime').declarePublic('DateTime')
```

It also contain this to allow import from four other utility builtin imports

```
for name in ('string', 'math', 'random', 'sets'):
    ModuleSecurityInfo(name).setDefaultAccess('allow')
```

So to do so, you need to add similar lines to the `__init__.py` of your Zope package (or create one if you haven't already, [see this tutorial](http://docs.zope.org/zope2/zdgbook/GettingStarted.html)), for instance:

```
from AccessControl import ModuleSecurityInfo
# just a specific class
ModuleSecurityInfo('datetime').declarePublic('datetime')
# or at a broader level for the entire module
ModuleSecurityInfo('datetime').setDefaultAccess('allow')
```

This of course assumes the package `datetime` is trusted enough to not be able to result in an attack against your Zope instance.

Answer (score 0):

just for the record, I had this error when using `strftime` in a TAL expression (RestrictedPython) :

```
The container has no security assertions.
Access to 'strftime' of datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 31, 0, 0) denied.
```

I solved this by using `allow_type` from `AccessControl` :

```
from AccessControl import allow_type
from datetime import datetime
allow_type(datetime)
```

Gauthier